# Tools required for jailbroken Device applications

Tags: iphone

I like to know about teh various tools required to develop for jailbroken application.

I have seen many links dealing with jailbroken devices says about the Open Toolchain . Does it really required for developing applications for jailbroken devices. Can anyone clearly elaborates regarding the open toolchain and other development tools required.

Do we need to sign the applications developed for jailbroken devices. Cant we use the normal provision profile downloaded from apple developer site for signing the application to run in the jailbroken devices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Wishes,
Mohammed Sadiq.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do programming after jailbreaking my iPhone? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565143/how-to-do-programming-after-jailbreaking-my-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of jailbroken app devs use the official SDK, and why wouldn't you?

Comment: jer, then why developers opt for toolchain. how it is advantageous over xcode in developing for jailbreaking iPhones. Does toolchain offers more api's and documentation than the xcode offers for the private framework.

Comment: It is a stable development environment, with LOTS of tools. A good debugger, Instruments, Interface Builder... You don't get things like Instruments and IB with the unofficial toolchain. Use what you want

Answer (score 0):

The applications should be the same. It's the distribution method that differs. The last two FAQs [here](http://cydia.saurik.com/faq/repositories.html) should help you.